# Как разделить слово на буквы в app inventor 2

Tags: android

Доброго времени подскажите как разделить слово на буквы в app inventor 2? и возможно ли в целом в  app inventor 2 разделить слово в строке на буквы? спасибо за помощь[image: введите сюда описание изображения]